# TensorBoard shows different metrics for models

Tags: tensorflow, metrics, tensorboard

I am training 4 different models and using Tensorboard.
I am not sure why it show the loss for only two of the models and epoch_loss for the other two. what are the difference? Is there anything I missed? how can I join these two graphs?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more info? How large is your data set? What changes between the different models? How many epochs and steps are you performing?

Comment: I used the same dataset. MNIST like dataset and I want to compare between 4 different CNN models (vgg,inception,resnet,inceptionresnet). and 150 epochs for all.

Comment: What type of network are you using? How large is your dataset? Since you are using the MNIST dataset, how many images are you using? How many steps are you performing per epoch?

Comment: Those are the networks (vgg,inception,resnet,inceptionresnet). and the dataset contains 24k images. with batch size 32

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to uncheck a model and see if the other models are just hiding underneath it? If they aren't there, I would guess that there is an error in those corresponding networks where the model isn't being fitted correctly, or the loss values aren't being logged correctly.

Comment: there are no models hiding underneath. Is there any way to combine the loss with the epoch_loss? I assume they are the same

Comment: epoch loss is the the loss that is generated per epoch. The overall loss is the loss of the entire model.